# Relationship between m and n in filter of image processing

Tags: image-processing, convolution

I have a filter/kernel like

```
              | 1 1 1|
    H  = 1/m  | 1 n 1|
              | 1 1 1|
```

I want to know what is the relationship between m and n in this filter and how this relationship
effect the image using convolution.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't have to be any relationship between `n` and `m`, but if you want the convolution to be normalized, you need the sum of the kernel to be 1. In that case

```
m = 8 + n
```

The [wiki page on kernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28image_processing%29#Normalization) also explains that

> Normalization ensures that the pixel values in the output image are of
>   the same relative magnitude as those in the input image.

Otherwise if `m < 8 + n` they will be brighter, or if `m > 8 + n` they will be dimmer.

**NOTE**

As pointed out by BЈовић, changing `n` changes the action of the filter significantly (see comments on this question).

Comment: The question makes no sense (same for your answer). n determines how the filter behaves

Comment: @BЈовић: True, n determines how the filter behaves, but the title was "Relationship between m and n", so I explained...

Comment: It is much more complex then that. n=1, and you get low pass filter. n=-1 and you get band pass filter.

Comment: @BЈовић: Thanks, though, I think you're forgetting that the question was about the relationship between m and n. Not generally what is the effect of n. I've added a note about your comment to the answer